# How to scraping JSON data and transform all into table columns

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I tried getting json data from this website: https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/apippu/gis/sebaranEnergi/tahun/2022/param//kategori//subkategori/

I used the below code to scrape it

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/apippu/gis/sebaranEnergi/tahun/2022/param//kategori//subkategori/")

data = response.json()

data1 = data['rows']['32'], data['rows']['14'], data['rows']['36'], data['rows']['35'], data['rows']['64'], data['rows']['74'], data['rows']['16'], data['rows']['31'], data['rows']['94'], data['rows']['12'], data['rows']['33'], data['rows']['15'], data['rows']['11'], data['rows']['21'], data['rows']['72'], data['rows']['63'], data['rows']['52'], data['rows']['13'], data['rows']['73'], data['rows']['62'], data['rows']['18'], data['rows']['19'], data['rows']['51'], data['rows']['65'], data['rows']['53'], data['rows']['61'], data['rows']['82'], data['rows']['71'], data['rows']['34'], data['rows']['91'], data['rows']['81'], data['rows']['75'], data['rows']['17'], data['rows']['76'] 

data2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(data1), orient='columns')

data2.to_excel('klhk.xlsx')
```

But some of the data are not transformed into separate columns (below image link).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpbIg.png)

I want to make the values in the [nilai] column to be in separate columns also.

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Comment: It looks like your [nilai] column contains a list, you need to parse it additionally

Comment: Hi Alan, any example you can share ?